# Testing for equal and unequal variance: How do I work out the alpha value so that I can use the right f-crit table?

Tags: anova, variance, t-test, excel

I'm a stats noob and I'm following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tscL1fzjSTY) on how to work out whether the variances in 2 samples I intend to use in a 2-sample t-test are equal.

In the video he refers to an f-crit table for Alpha values of 0.05. How do I figure out what Alpha value my sample data has?

Comment: alpha is user specified. It is the [type I error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha values are typically assigned a default value of $p=0.05$ and if yours in not listed, that is likely what it is. In fact, for some statistical software implementations, alpha cannot even be changed. What that refers to is A.K.A. [type I error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) a type I error (alpha error) is the incorrect rejection of a true null hypothesis (a "false positive"), while a type II error (beta error) is incorrectly retaining a false null hypothesis (a "false negative"). More simply stated, a type I error is detecting an effect that is not present, while a type II error is failing to detect an effect that is present.

In effect, many users habitually find that it is acceptable to falsely accept a result 1 time in 20 in order to assign a calculate a p-value. Those p-values, in turn have the meaning that if they are less than 0.05, the results are "significant." Let's make up a beta error up, say the "answer" from the "alpha p=0.05" test is p=0.02. That means that there is a 2% probability of failing to detect significance and a 5% chance of that being a fictional result.

In some publications, e.g., the probability for finding an exoplanet, one sees 5 sigma tests. That would refer to a much lower alpha values because a lot can go wrong in exoplanet detection, and the astrophysicists want to be sure they didn't mess up and falsely identify a planet. After all, planets disappearing can be a source of embarrassment. BTW, can you find where I put Earth? Hello, Carl to Earth, are you there? My falsely accepting that Earth exists would be a type I or alpha error.